# Send multiple queries to EF / SQL database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

.NET 4.7.6 and Entity Framework 3.1.16

Is it possible to send multiple queries via EF or any other method when querying the database?

The problem I have is that I have to extract a lot of data from multiple tables with multiple queries for example (I have omitted unnecessary info)

```
var companyValues = GetCompanyValues(companyId); // DB query
var allMemberScores = GetAllMemberScores(companyId); // DB query
var currentPeriodMemberScores = GetAllMemberScores(companyId, timespan); // DB query
var previousPeriodMemberScores = GetAllMemberScores(companyId, previousTimespan); // DB query

var currentDepartments = allMemberScores.Select(x => x.Department).Distinct(); 

if (currentDepartments?.Any() == true)
{
    foreach (var department in currentDepartments)
    {
        var current = currentPeriodMemberScores.Where(x => x.Department.Equals(department));
        var previous = previousPeriodMemberScores.Where(x => x.Department.Equals(department)); 

        var combinedCompanyValueScore = allMemberScores.Where(x => x.Department.Equals(department)).SelectMany(x => x.CompanyValueScores).Average(x => x.Score);

        foreach (var companyValue in companyValues)
        {
            int? value = GetCompanyValueDifference(current, previous, companyValue); // DB query
        }

        int responseRate = GetResponseRate(surveysQuery, current); // DB query
    }
}
```

but this will send a lot of requests depending on the number of departments and company values both of which are undefined in length, could be 10 could be 20+ etc.

This is an inherited project, so there is existing data etc. and redesigning the database is on the backseat.

I have previously used Elastic search in another project where I could define a search request that takes in multiple queries and give each query an id, and on the object that is returned pull it the response for each of those ids.

Is there anything like this that I could utilise? So could I build up a query and then process all the results?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Would adding a view count as redesigning the database?

Comment: That's not something I have thought about, I'll look into it

Comment: No, EntityFramework is not ElasticSearch. I think you have at least a couple options, one is adding a function (assuming SQL Server) to return a table and move all your logic to the database. This would accept parameters like your companyId, etc. Alternatively, request *more* data upfront with EF and do the filtering/aggregating on the app side.